# Complex number literal

Tags: ruby, literals, complex-numbers

A complex number can be written as a literal like this:

```
3 + 2i # => (3+2i)
```

How is this syntactically distinguished from the case where receiver integer `3` receives the method `+` with argument `2i` (which itself works as a literal for a complex number `(0+2i)`)?

Comment: BTW, `+` is actually called 3 times: (1) `3 + (0+2i)` delegates to Complex, (2) `(0+2i) + 3` which in turn calls (3) `0 + 3` to calculate the real part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: it doesn't. The way it works is that the `+` method of integer receives the imaginary unit and returns a `Complex`. So in terms of literals you have the usual integer and floating point literals as well as imaginary number literal (e.g. `2i`) and by combining them you can construct complex values.

Comment: But the document https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Complex.html says that literals like `2+1i` can be used. Is this document inaccurate or misleading?

Comment: I think it's just a looser use of the term literal. Basically it does not matter what the intermediate steps Ruby does are if you get the complex value in the end. In any case you can use `2+1i` and it will behave as expected

Answer (score 3):

I guess the documentation is misleading and what appears to be literal is really method call. I made an experiment that confirms this:

```
class Integer
  alias old_plus +

  def +(*args)
    puts 'called with complex' if args.first.class == Complex
    old_plus(*args)
  end
end

8+3i
# called with complex
# => (8+3i)
(9+2i)
# called with complex
# => (9+2i)
```

Comment: I was just doing something similar to confirm what Svetlin Simonyan has written. It looks like he is correct, as well as you. Thanks.

Comment: Running `ruby --dump=parsetree -e '3+2i'` also confirms that it's actually two literals and a method call.